# Network driver missing in arch installation

Tags: drivers, arch-linux, dell-xps, wifi-driver

I'm trying to install Arch on my Dell XPS 13 9343, intel core i7 inside, but I always had some drivers problem during Linux installations. Particularly, I always had to manually install Wireless driver even after Ubuntu or other Linux installation. Then my question: how can I get and manually install driver during the arch installation?
I'm trying to install it on a VM before installing it on the host. There are some commands provided:

**ON THE HOST:**

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -i net
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 03
       serial: 2c:33:7a:f5:f3:b9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.171.122 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff

$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Note that command `lspci` doesn't return anything even if I'm currently connected to wireless.
I'm currently on NixOS.

**ON THE GUEST:**

```
# lspci -nn | grep -i net
00:03:0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:100e] (rev 02)
# lshw -C network
zsh: command not found: lshw
# rfkill list
#
```

Note that command `rfkill` doesn't return anything.

What can i try to continue the installation? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I tried to run a bootable arch usb flashdrive and I can't ping because `Network is unreachable`. The output of previous commands are:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -i net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. And subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
# lshw -C network
zsh: command not found: lshw
# rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
# ip link
1: lo: <LOOOBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Comment: You might have to change driver with `modprobe`. Check lspci -k. (For the installation, you need either of [these](https://archlinux.org/packages/?q=broadcom-wl) I suppose. Probably have to blacklist the kernel driver (i.e. the one you need to `modprobe -r` in the live environment).

Comment: How could i get them?? I really dont know how to proceed, also because my pc hasn't other connection adapter

Comment: The Arch ISO have the package included, but apparently you need to switch to the right one. (The in-tree one is apparently used by default even when it doesn't support the particular device.) After switching driver you should follow usual instruction to connect to WiFi (e.g. iwd), then you can install the package for your installation when pacstrap (or arch-chroot and pacman if you missed it).

Comment: And how can i switch to the correct one?? Sorry im new with these things...

Comment: Broadcom chipsets are always a pain. You must always install them after the OS. Make peace with it.

Comment: As I said, check `lspci -k` for the names of the two drivers, then `modprobe -r CURRENT; modprobe THE_OTHER`.